# How to input fractional numbers in editText?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am a begnner in android studio, and I want to build an app where the user can input numbers in the form a/b in editText. The number will be later divided and further calculated. It is not possible to enter number in the form a/b in either Number(editText) or decimal(editText). What should I use?

Thanks a lot guys! Finally I made this piece of code that does the work for me:

```
var fractionString = editText_input.text.toString() //the fraction is taken as a string with '/' in it
var splitFraction = Fraction.split('/')
var numerator = splitFraction[0]
var denominator = splitFraction[1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about two `EditText` : one for the numerator and one for the denominator?

Or use a String `EditText` to which you add a `TextChanger`with `myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextChanger())`.

The code for the `MyTextChanger` is below :

```
public class MyTextChanger implements TextWatcher {
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    int i;
    boolean modified=false;

    for (i = 0; (i < s.length()) && !modified; i++) {
        if (((s.charAt(i) < '0') || (s.charAt(i) > '9')) && (s.charAt(i) != '/')) {
            s.delete(i,i+1);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't want to keep 2 editTexts for numerator and denominator, but the second alternative is a good idea. As I am a beginner, can you please give some code on how to override onKey, as you said?

Comment: See the modified anwer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code! But what will be my final result? I mean I need a variable in the end with the value of a/b (a = numerator, b = denominator)

Comment: Read the string, split it with `String.split("/")`, convert the two strings obtained and perform the division.